# Arithmetic within numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I have read 3 raster images of equal shape (500 by 500) as numpy array, and have put them in this way:

```
rasters = np.array(A,B,C)
```

Where A, B, C are 2d numpy arrays belonging to each image.

Now I have to calculate the followings:

```
result1 = B-A
result2 = C-B
```

Then,

```
final_result = np.max([result1,result2],axis = 0)
```

The final_result should have the same shape of A or B or C (i.e., 500 by 500)

How can I do it?

Comment: Is the issue getting A.B and C out of `rasters`, or doing the subtractions, or something else?

Comment: The issue is to doing substractions

Comment: `np.array(A,B,C)` or `np.array([A,B,C])`?

Comment: np.array([A,B,C]). sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.diff` and `np.max`:

```
np.max(np.diff(rasters, axis=0), axis=0)
```

Alternatively:

```
np.max(rasters[1:] - rasters[:-1], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

B-A is accomplished using `np.subtract(B,A)`.

Comment: In my real problem, A, B, C...are many. So looking for pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: And, I want to do it from the 'rasters'.

Comment: @simen: So "I have read 3 raster images" was not exactly true, nor was "The issue is doing subtractions".  Good to know.